# Creating a dashed seperator in navi bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal separator for my navigation bar, similar to this:

[image]

I've created a simple unlisted navigation bar in HTML, and created a transparent GIF and applied it to the background. While the effect is what I'm trying to achieve I feel the spacing is a bit off and I can't seem to correct it.

Heres my CSS code:

```
.on {
    display: inline; 
    background-image:url(images/seperator.gif);
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.last {
    background-image: none;
    padding-left: 0;

}

ul {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

li {    
    display: inline;    
    margin: 0px 3px;
}

a {
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 20px 5px 10px;
}
```

Here is the HTML for the navi bar:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="on">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="on">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="on">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="on last">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: I've updated it with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `li:not(:last-child)` selector to exclude the last `li` and add dotted `border-right`.

```css
.on {
  display: inline;
  background-image: url(images/seperator.gif);
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.last {
  background-image: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px 3px;
}
a {
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px 5px 10px;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="on">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="on">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="on">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="on last">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to change the separator’s `height`, you could use a :pseudo-element instead.

```css
.on {
  display: inline;
  background-image: url(images/seperator.gif);
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.last {
  background-image: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
a {
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px 5px 10px;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  top: -25%;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: -1;
  border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="on">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="on">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="on">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="on last">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the height of the border?

Comment: @Wolf - Yes if you use a :pseudo-element instead. I'll add another snippet.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much for you help. one last question how am I able to center the text; i've removed the text-align: left to text-align:right but it won't budge.

Comment: @Wolf - Change the `padding` in `a` from `padding: 6px 20px 5px 10px` to `padding: 6px 20px 5px 20px;` or `padding: 6px 10px 5px 10px;`. The second and last values must be same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
li{
    display: block;
    border-right: dashed black;
}
```

Comment: I tried that previously before  creating my own separator but I wasn't too happy with the result as it felt a bit tacky.

Comment: @Wolf, once LI is of block type and has border applied, you can manipulate paddings and margins to achieve best results.